# Ubuntu 16.04 take 5 minutes to bootup

Tags: boot

Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T61 with 4GB RAM.

Since the upgrade from 14.04, Ubuntu is taking more than 5 minutes to start. From dmesg, I identified two sections below that consumed the most seconds. But I have no idea what I should do. Can anyone share some insight? thanks much.

```
[   27.002297] audit: type=1400 audit(1483808627.513:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer" pid=9 35 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  102.305230] **cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored**

[  152.080602] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  237.887583] wls3: authenticate with ec:aa:a0:a2:88:38
```

---

```
zhoub@erdbeer:~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 6.430s (kernel) + 3min 3.345s (userspace) = 3min 9.775s
zhoub@erdbeer:~$ systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20
         40.804s docker.service
         18.212s winbind.service
         18.171s nmbd.service
         17.509s samba-ad-dc.service
         10.116s ModemManager.service
          9.270s dev-sda5.device
          9.216s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          8.978s dev-sda8.device
          6.893s NetworkManager.service
          6.049s accounts-daemon.service
          4.595s gpu-manager.service
          4.026s thermald.service
          3.915s vboxdrv.service
          3.328s apparmor.service
          3.282s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7a44ebaa\x2d3c90\x2d4dc0\x2db73d\x2df4514bf902cb.service
          3.165s colord.service
          2.809s lightdm.service
          2.516s lvm2-monitor.service
          2.374s console-kit-log-system-start.service
          2.262s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b1e33271\x2d0169\x2d4110\x2d915c\x2d1a5494277e1b.service
```

Comment: The output of `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20` might also be helpful. Could you please [edit] your question to add those? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for answering at this early hours. here the output:

Comment: Early hours? This is an international community, so somebody is always awake ;-) I'm probably not able to solve your problem though, just preparing the ground for those who know more about that topic than me...

Comment: Suspecting a resizing the partitions with gparted might have caused some problem, I run the command update-grub2 to resolve any problem. But that seems to have no effect at all.

Comment: I wonder what the following is telling me, and what I should do. it took over a minute between the two steps.                                                              cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored

Comment: [   37.580382] audit: type=1400 audit(1483829678.106:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer" pid=966 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  100.984790] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored

Comment: Please edit your question to add info, especially console output. It's almost unreadable in comments because of the lack of formatting and people will likely miss it.

Comment: I found one culprit, there're two entries for the same swap partition, one point to a wrong partition's UUID. I commented that line out. Now it starts in a little over one minute, as recorded in dmesg output. But it actually take longer.

Comment: Would you please post your solution in the answer section? Thanks.